# Get partially filled HTMLInputElement date value

Tags: date, html-input

I've added support to my database for partial date strings, since `YYYY-MM` is a valid ISO date, however I've noticed that HTML's input element will always return an empty string if the day isn't selected.

Is there a way around this or am I resigned to using a custom option?

To clarify, if I have the HTML of

```html
<input type="date" id="date-field" />
```

and enter the date, 2023-04 (leaving the day field blank). When I get that element in JavaScript and get the `value` attribute, it's an empty string and will be until that day field is entered.